# How can I let people drag and drop LI's to a specific place in a list? (console.log issues)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

**I'm facing two issues, one of which is a goal and one of which is failure to obtain information from console.log() calls.**

Let's look at the goal first:

I have a JSfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/L7sbhzzj/ for a project I'm working on. The code I'm working on is:

```
jQuery('.collection').droppable(
    {
    'accept': '.collection > li',
    'drop': function(e, ui)
        {
        console.log('Reached here!');
        console.log(this);
        jQuery('#selection').append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
```

Essentially, I want people to be able to drag and drop elements to a specific position on a list. So, in the JSfiddle, you can drag "Fiction" to the right, but if you do that and then drag over "Nonfiction", "Nonfiction" is only added to the end; you cannot subsequently drag "Nonfiction" to be above and before "Fiction".

I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel on this; I imagine there is some standard pattern like "Put the LI being dropped immediately before the target UL's LI that has the lowest distance to the top of the page but is still equal or greater than the dropped LI's distance to the top of the page."

Now to return to the other issue I'm facing: either `jQuery('#selection').append(ui.draggable);` is working or something else is doing equivalent work, but none of my console.log()s seem to be reported.

I have some ideas for how to implement something, but it would be nice to introspect and obtain console.log()s' diagnostic output while I'm working on things.

Is the `'drop'` taking effect at all? Is it working some other way? How can I get things like what element the object was dropped to?

**--EDIT--**

I realized that I'd asked for one side of what I want to. I'd like people to be able to take item XYZ from one container to another and then back if they change their mind. Snowmonkey's solution worked beautifully for the right list being sortable. However, the following adaptation failed, perhaps because I called two incompatible enhancements:

```
jQuery(function()
{
jQuery('#selection').sortable(
    {
    });
jQuery('li', jQuery('#source')).draggable(
    {
    'connectToSortable': '#selection',
    'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
    'revert': 'invalid',
    'containment': 'document',
    'cursor': 'move'
    });
jQuery('#source').sortable(
    {
    });
jQuery('li', jQuery('#selection')).draggable(
    {
    'connectToSortable': '#selection',
    'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
    'revert': 'invalid',
    'containment': 'document',
    'cursor': 'move'
    });
```

How can I get a fully two-sided variation of Snowmonkey's answer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to connect a draggable to a sortable? Here's a simple way. Get rid of the droppable altogether, and simply add the 'connectToSortable' rule to your draggable. Thus, #selection remains a sortable and #source remains a draggable, that can drop into any position on #source.

```js
jQuery(function() {

  $(".collection").sortable({
  });
  
  jQuery('li', jQuery('.collection')).draggable({
    'connectToSortable': '.collection',
    'cancel': 'a.ui-icon',
    'revert': 'invalid',
    'containment': 'document',
    'cursor': 'move'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia;
}

div.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 440px;
}

div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 440px;
}

div.td {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

div.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

ul.collection {
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

ul.collection > li {}

ul#selection {
  float: right;
}

ul#source {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">
        <ul id="source" class="collection">
          <li>Everything</li>
          <li>Nonfiction</li>
          <li>Fiction</li>
          <li>Poetry</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="td">
        <ul id="selection" class="collection">
          <li>Empty</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

So i updated the above post to make it work in both directions. Rather than using the ID for the two elements, I used the class that they have in common. Both .collection elements are sortable, and both connectToSortable .collection elements. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you (for my background, what did you to get your answer formatted that way? It's lovely!). This has the right side sortable as desired, but as now edited in the question, I'd like the functionality to work both ways. Would you be willing to reread the expanded question and tell how to make it work both ways? Thanks,

Comment: @JonathanHayward, I updated the code block above to do what you were looking for. I'd used the IDs to make it explicit, but if you want it to work bi-directionally, simply use the classes rather than the IDs. And when I was doing my answer, I clicked on the 'Code' button above my text input field to create the pretty-format working code. ;)

Comment: Ok; thank you. There's one CSS note I was wondering if you had comment on (should I ask a separate question?): if either UL is empty, it is staggered as in https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/project/staggered.png; they appear to me to be staggered so that the top of one is flush with the bottom of the other, and there is a nasty flicker effect transferring the last element from left to right. What I want, and what happens when they are both nonempty, is for them to both be flush at the top all the time, as in https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/project/flush.png. Any way to force this in CSS?

Comment: Easiest way? change the CSS as I've done above: float one to the left and the other to the right. thus, they move independently of each other. Or, happily, they don't move at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want just using jquery ui sortable. If you want to be notified whenever an item added to selection, you can listen for receive event.

```
jQuery(function()
{
 jQuery( "#source" ).sortable({
   connectWith: "#selection",
}).disableSelection();

jQuery("#selection").sortable({
    receive: function() {
    console.log("changed");
   }
})
});
```